# Get last line from grep search on multiple files, and write them in a output file

Tags: linux, bash

I have multiple files located in multiple directories. From them I search a keyword 'ENERGY' by grep. In each file I get multiple match cases. I want to take the last line from each file and save the results in the output.txt file. I wrote the following code:

```
labl=SubDir
ENERGY=`grep 'ENERGY' MyDir*${labl}*/*.txt`

cat > output.txt << EOF

${ENERGY}

EOF
```

This code saves all match cases from each file. But as mentioned, I need the last match case from each file. For that I modified the grep command as:

```
ENERGY=`grep 'ENERGY' MyDir*${labl}*/*.txt|taile -l`
```

Unfortunately this doesn't do the job either. Instead, it saves all the match cases from the last file only.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't run multiple processes/pipes to achieve this.

```
 gawk '/ENERGY/{last=$0} ENDFILE{if(last!="") print last; last=""}' MyDir*"$labl"*/*.txt
```

- `/ENERGY/{last=$0}`: On lines which match the regex `ENERGY`, set variable `last` to the contents of the entire line `$0`
- `ENDFILE{...}` Run this `{action}` at the end of every input file supplied by the glob.
- `if(last!="") print last`: print `last` if it's not null
- `last=""`: reset this variable to null, avoiding duplication
- `MyDir*"${labl}"*/*.txt`: Quoted variable in glob will match directory names that include spaces

Comment: Note that this doesn't cleanly handle files that don't match the string, but this is definitely the right approach.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Good catch; fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for f in MyDir*"$lab1"*/*.txt; do
   grep ENERGY "$f" | tail -1 >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: @oguzismail OP didn't mention needing the filename. He just says he wants the last matching line from each file placed into `output.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet one but probably not last possible approach is to use parallel like this. Probably you can achieve the same with xargs, but I personally prefer parallel as simpler and giving the possibility to scale your process.

```
ls -1 file* | parallel -j1 "grep ENERGY {} | tail -n 1" > output.txt
```